# Hahn Banach type extension of a Lipschitz map

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, hahn-banach-theorem

The problem that I posted was a much generalized form of what I had in my mind. All I want to know the literature of Hahn-Banach type extension of Lipschitz map. I know only about the result by Kirszbrzun and very few of its development. The main problem is:

> Let $X$ be a real Banach space, $Y$ a subspace of it and $f$ a $1$-Lipschitz map from $Y$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Is it possible to get an extension of $f$ from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$ with Lipschitz constant $1$?

The case when $X$ is a metrizable tvs  and $Y$ a finite dimensional subspace follows from MR0737400(86a:46018). But can we say anything about a infinite dimensional $Y$? Let us assume $X=C(K)$, $K$ is compact, $T_2$ (assume metrizable too if you want) and $Y=\{f\in X:f|_D=0\}$ (i.e. an M-ideal) of $X$. Now can a real valued $1$-Lipschitz map from $Y$ necessarily have a similar extension? Will it be unique ?

Comment: The question doesn't make sense --- there is no notion of distance in an LCTVS.

Comment: Okay, I mean a metrizable lctvs but not necessarily normed linear space.

Comment: I knew only about the result by Kirszbrzun but not any further development.Here is what I would like to ask.Let $X$ be a real Banach sp,$Y$ a subspace of it and $f$ a 1-Lip map from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$.Is it possible to get an extn of $f$ from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$ with Lip constant 1? The case when $X$ is a metric sp and $Y$ a finite dim. subsp, the result follows from MR0737400(86a:46018).But let us assume $X=C(K)$,$K$ is cpt $T_2$(can assume metrizable also)and $Y=\{f:f|_D=0\}$ (ie an M-ideal) of $X$.Now can a real valued 1-Lip map from $Y$ necessarily has a similar extn ? Can it be unique ?

Comment: I suggest that you "unaccept" the answer below, otherwise people will think that your question has been fully answered and move on without looking

Comment: Lipschitz maps defined on subspaces of Hilbert spaces and taking values in an arbitrary Banach space extend to Lipschitz maps (with the same Lipschitz constant) on the whole space. However, I shall deeply appreciate to know if the result extends to type 2 Banach space in place of Hilbert spaces, this time with the mappings also taking values in a Hilbert space. The linear analogue of this statement, with linear maps being used in place of Lipschitz maps is a well known theorem of B. Maurey.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If $X$ is any metric space, $Y$ any subset of $X$, and $f: Y \to \mathbb{R}$ a Lipschitz function, then there is an extension $\tilde{f}: X \to \mathbb{R}$ of $f$ with the same Lipschitz constant. This easy result (just extend the function one point at a time) has been rediscovered many times. See Theorem 1.5.6 of my book *Lipschitz Algebras*.

The result does not follow from the paper of Johnson and Lindenstrauss that you mention. The case when $X$ is "metrizable" is meaningless as you need an actual metric to have a notion of Lipschitz map. The answer by MKO is basically unrelated to the question as far as I can tell.